# alternatives to virtualbox to reassemble vdi snapshots

Tags: virtualbox

My virtual box xml files became corrupted when my computer ran out of space (both the .vbox and .vbox-prev).  However, the .vdi files and snapshots are fine.  Whenever I try to use VBoxManage it keeps complaining about the xml files being messed up.  Is there another program that can re-assemble the snapshots into the base vdi file?

Comment: Long time ago I managed to slove this problem many time by removing the last snapshot entry (or problem making one) from the xml file, one by one until problem solved (error message will help you to find). Also remove xml parts.

Answer (score 0):

From the thread
[Reconstructing VM from Backup - possible?](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=54067&start=0#p248332) :

> The only cure is to create a temp folder, copy in the base VDI
>   (.VirtualBox\HardDisks\hatchery.vdi), then copy in all the snapshot
>   VDIs from your backup. The .sav files are ignored.
>
> Use the [**CloneVDI tool**](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=22422) to clone the newest snapshot VDI, **do not** make the mistake
>   of cloning the base vdi. The clone will be a merge of the snapshot
>   chain starting with the base vdi and ending with the selected
>   snapshot.
>
> You can build a new VM around the clone. Be careful to get
>   the VM recipe as close as possible to the old one, I would copy hdd
>   controller type, IO APIC setting, network card MAC address, RAM size.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Tool "VM Snapshot Manager" for exactly that purpose, which you can get from here: https://github.com/BOfH85/VM_Snapshot_Manager/tree/en-us

Why using this project instead of the build in Snapshot-Manager of Virtualbox?
Well, first of all, this program was developed as a quick and dirty solution for VM Workstation Player which doesn't even have the option to create Snapshots.

Furthermore I discovered that even with Virtualbox it is better if you store your snapshots as 7Zip-compressed 1:1 copies of your full vdi or vmdk File. Virtualbox splits the data in a complex manner if you create snapshots there which makes it quick to create one but takes also a long time to restore.

And you always need the whole tree of snapshots if you want to clone or move your VM - you can't just take your .vdi File, ignore all the Snapshot-Files and mount it in a new machine as Hard Drive - the data won't be the same as your last working point in the old machine.

If you don't do snapshots with the program at all und use this tool instead, you always keep your min vdi or vmdk File 100% complete and movable.

It's a terminal based python program which uses 7zip to high-compress your current VMDK-File (or VDI-File since you also can use it with Virtual Box). It basically copies and compresses your vmdk-harddrive and can restore the compressed files so that you can jump back and forward to any backuped state you created in the past.
It's necessary for the program to work that you store your VM in only one vmdk-File and don't split it up in several files.

Maybe this tool is helpful - if so just spread the news, it's free